# Attempting to ativate product with activation code

Tags: xamarin.android

We are attempting to activate Mono for Android.  After loading version monoandroid-1.0.0.10192, which does not ask for the activation code by the way, running a project in Visual Studio 2010 works as expected.  But when you attempt to run the project it is still in evaluation mode and will not allow downloads to devices.

Clicking 'Click to activate' works properly.

A window pops up asking for information.  After entering all necessary information (with activation code), the activate button runs a program called, mandroid.exe, in the task manager -- some kind of command line program.
It runs for about 3 seconds and does nothing.  No status report or anything.

Activation is impossible.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

You activate it on the Window that comes up asking you to select an emulator, there is a small link that says "Click here to activate".  The reason it is placed there, albeit very difficult to find is because the Trial version is ONLY limited by being able to not deploy to a physical device.

To get there:
1. Close all emulators
2. Run Application
3. Dialog will appear
4. Click Link to Activate

Hope that helps!

Comment: I do exactly that, and the actuvation dialog pops up twice, each time I click "Activate Mono for Android", then MonoDevelop returns to coding state. (ie. my app isn't even installed) I've tried after reinstalling MonoDevelop and MonoDroid. What am I missing?

Comment: We know about the link: tech support had this to say about a month ago, still no response.
>Let me apologize for the delays this is causing you.  We're getting this behavior reported from several customers attempting to activate behind corporate proxy servers.  We're investigating and will hopefully have a fix or a workaround available soon, and will update you as soon as possible.

Again, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Thank you
Joseph